# How to detect player joining a Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a 1.12 map that need to do something when a player join. I tried `stats.leavegame` method, but if the game crashed the last time, the command won't run.

No file permission for it's hard to share, but unintended file type (like using a file to take the place of a folder, in my answer) is fine

Comment: Yay, someone who shows what they tried before!

Comment: So you want to detect every join, not just the first, right? There are certainly ways to detect when the player is there or not, but I'm trying to find a not very laggy, elegant way. I have some ideas already, I'll try some things in the next hours, for example if `scoreboard tag` on offline players can be used here.

Comment: @Fabian Using tag seems can only detect players except the first one

Comment: @Virusbomb Checked the dup source, it assumes on a server, so if it crashes a local fix can be done; Here is a map where you shouldn't require to do something just because of unnormal shutdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self solved , experiment under discussion with chyx

The world loads before player join even if it's single player, so freely assume at the beginning there's no player:

```
give @a[score_onLine=0] iron_shovel
scoreboard players set * onLine 0
scoreboard players set @a onLine 1
```

Comment: Someone has requested in a suggested edit that you add `scoreboard players add @a onLine 0` at the start, because, *This won't register players joining for the first time.*. I rejected this edit because it changes the post's meaning. Although it can seem like a good addition, so you may want to consider adding it.